# だけなくねぇ what does it mean?

Tags: reading-comprehension, negation, particle-だけ

暇だったから読んでたんだけど、お前　この漫画　7巻だけなくねぇ

I understand the character is saying "I had free time so I was reading, but you, this manga..."

What I don't quite understand is the final nuance.

You only have 7 volumes of this manga? You are only missing volume 7? I'm aware of だけでなく but here there is no で

Answer (score 1):

なくねえ is contracted/colloquial version of なくない used in the question sense and related to the of yours

- [What does じゃなくない mean? Is it a positive?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/101800/45489)

Similarly:

- 7巻だけない = Only Vol. 7 is missing
- 7巻だけなくない? = Only Vol. 7 is missing, isn't it?

So it is more or less 'You are only missing volume 7?'.